# TypeError: open() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is the code:

```
def save():
    f = open('table.html', 'w')
    f.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>\n")
    f.write("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>\n")
    f.write("<head profile='http://gmpg.org/xfn/11'>\n")
    f.write('<title>Table</title>')
    f.write("<style type='text/css'>")
    f.write('body {margin-left:0;margin-right:0;font:normal normal 800 18px Arial;}')
    f.write('a{ text-decoration: }')
    f.write(':link { color: rgb(0, 0, 255) }')
    f.write(':visited {color :rgb(100, 0,100) }')
    f.write(':hover { }')
    f.write(':active { }')
    f.write('table{position: relative; empty-cells: show;border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse}')
    f.write('td{position: relative; border: 1px solid black; text-align: left; padding: 0px 5px 0px 1px}')
    f.write('.tr1{background: #EEFFF9}')
    f.write('.tr2{background: #FFFEEE}')
    f.write('</style>')
    f.write('</head>')
    f.write('<body>')
    f.write('<center>2012 La Jolla Half Marathon</center><br />')
    f.write('<table>')
    f.close()
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\GUICreator1.py", line 11, in save
    f = open('table.html', 'w')
TypeError: open() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

I know open takes 2 arguments.
Also, if I run the same code not within the function it runs properly with no error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have, elsewhere in your module, a function named `open()` (defined or imported) that masks the built-in. Rename it.

As for your `save()` function, you should really use multi-line string, using triple-quoting, to save yourself so many `f.write()` calls:

```
def save():
    with open('table.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write("""\
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>\n
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>\n
<head profile='http://gmpg.org/xfn/11'>\n
<title>Table</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {margin-left:0;margin-right:0;font:normal normal 800 18px Arial;}
a{ text-decoration: }
:link { color: rgb(0, 0, 255) }
:visited {color :rgb(100, 0,100) }
:hover { }
:active { }
table{position: relative; empty-cells: show;border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse}
td{position: relative; border: 1px solid black; text-align: left; padding: 0px 5px 0px 1px}
.tr1{background: #EEFFF9}
.tr2{background: #FFFEEE}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>2012 La Jolla Half Marathon</center><br />
<table>""")
```

This also uses the open file object as a context manager, which means Python will close it for you automacally.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, which I found and corrected. I had discovered that and renamed the offending function and it is working correctly The text I had put in there was just for testing, it was not meant for actual use. I have since put in my real code, which was to write the contents of a text widget to a file. That is working beautifully, as is the opening of a file and inserting the text into a text widget. What I am doing is creating a python IDE, in which I can create a tkinter GUI without writing any code.