# I try to make Dataframe from multiple text files and got error message

Tags: python

I try to create Dataframe from multiple text files.
Following as code.

```
text_keep_dir = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\txt\\"

results = defaultdict(list)
for file in Path(text_keep_dir).iterdir():
    with open(file, "r") as file_open:
        results["file_name"].append(file.name)
        results["text"].append(file_open.read())
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

And I got error message.

> ---> 53     with open(file, "r") as file_open:

> TypeError: open() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

I try to check from another questions. but I cannot fix it. Please support me. How to fix this error ?

Comment: Does this help? [TypeError: open() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387580/typeerror-open-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open is not recognizing PurePath that is returned by Path().iterdirs(), You need to use [`p.as_posix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) this will represent the path as a file URI

```
text_keep_dir = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\txt\\"

results = defaultdict(list)
for file in Path(text_keep_dir).iterdir():
    with open(file.as_posix(), "r") as file_open:
        results["file_name"].append(file.name)
        results["text"].append(file_open.read())
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

or you can use p.open()

```
text_keep_dir = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\txt\\"
    
    results = defaultdict(list)
    for file in Path(text_keep_dir).iterdir():
        with file.open() as file_open:
            results["file_name"].append(file.name)
            results["text"].append(file_open.read())
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: Oh!! Thank you very much. I can use p.open()